# How do I remove FLX trail or change it's parent object or image?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib, lime-haxe

I'm trying to change an object whilst using an Flx trails, but it doesn't update when the object changes. This causes the entire trail to continue till the last frame of the animation where it stays on screen behind the new object. If someone could tell me how to update the trail or remove it entirely so I can add a new one in, that would be great.

I've tried connecting it to a var but that doesn't seem to allow me to create the trail.
I've also tried the different Methods on the HaxeFlixel website, but to no avail.
This is the code I used to create the trail.

```
game.insert(game.members.indexOf(game.dadGroup) - 1, new FlxTrail(game.dad, null, 4, 24, 0.3, 0.069));
```